# `TypeError`: `checkbox` is `null` when trying to add an event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I press the checkbox but tasks are not deleted and the message is not shown.

I tried to debug this in Firefox and it shows this error: *“`TypeError`: `checkbox` is `null`”* at the line I marked below.

```js
var list = document.querySelector('.list');
var items = list.children;
var emptyListMessage = document.querySelector('.no-tasks-message');

//functions

var toggleEmptyListMessage = function() {
  if (items.length === 0) {
    emptyListMessage.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
  else if (items.length > 0) {
    emptyListMessage.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
var addCheckHandler = function(item) {
  var checkbox = item.querySelector('.checkbox');
  
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() { // This line throws the error.
    item.remove();
    toggleEmptyListMessage();
  });
};

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  addCheckHandler(items[i]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title>To-do App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--To-Do List-->
  <div class="todo-list">

    <!--List-->
    <ul class="list">

      <!--Template-->
      <template id="task-template">
        <li class="list-item">
          <div class="task-label">
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="task-n" name="task">
            <label class="label" for="task-n"></label>
          </div>
          <div class="delete-btn">Delete</div>
        </li>
      </template>
      <!--Template-->

      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="task-label">
          <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="task-1" name="task">
          <label class="label" for="task-1">Eat</label>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-btn">Delete</div>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <!--List-->


    <p class="no-tasks-message hidden">
      No tasks left
    </p>
    <input class="input" type="text" required>
    <input class="add-btn" type="submit" value="Add">
  </div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _“I tried to debug in Firefox”_ — the next step would be to confirm that, during execution, you have an element with the class `checkbox` inside your `item`, that `item` is an element that exists in your DOM, and so on. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre], including your HTML. You’re using selectors for HTML we can’t see.

Comment: It would greatly help if you would provide a complete sample of your code, i. e. including your relevant  HTML markup.

Comment: The minimal HTML fragment, implied by the JavaScript, necessary for this particular error to not be thrown anymore is something like `<ul class="list"> <li> <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> </li> </ul>`, available during script execution. Do you have something like that? See [How to create Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212).

Comment: Added HTML code

Comment: Your `<template>` doesn’t contain a `.checkbox` element (`<template>` do not ever contain _any_ elements). You’ll have to exclude it from iteration.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now with your HTML markup, look at the following:

```js
var taskid=3, list = document.querySelector('.list');
var children = list.children;
var emptyListMessage = document.querySelector('.no-tasks-message');
var tmpl = document.querySelector('#task-template');
var inp = document.querySelector('.input');

list.onclick=ev=>{       // click handler associated with div.list
                         // will only do something, if the element is of class "checkbox":
 if (ev.target.classList.contains("checkbox")){ 
   ev.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
   emptyListMessage.classList.toggle('hidden',children.length);  // hide or show message
 }
};

document.querySelector('.add-btn').onclick=ev=>
  list.innerHTML+=tmpl.innerHTML.replace(/@1/g, inp.value).replace(/@2/g,++taskid)
```

```css
.hidden {display: none}
```

```html
<div class="todo-list">

    <!--List-->
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="task-label">Task No. 1
          <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="task-1" name="task">
          <label class="label" for="task-1">Eat</label>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-btn">Delete</div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="task-label">Task No. 2
          <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="task-2" name="task">
          <label class="label" for="task-2">Eat</label>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-btn">Delete</div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="task-label">Task No. 3
          <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="task-3" name="task">
          <label class="label" for="task-3">Eat</label>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-btn">Delete</div>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <!--List-->
    <!--Template-->
      <template id="task-template">
        <li class="list-item">
          <div class="task-label">Task No. @2
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="task-@2" name="task">
            <label class="label" for="task-n">@1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="delete-btn">Delete</div>
        </li>
      </template>
      <!--Template-->
    <p class="no-tasks-message hidden">
      No tasks left
    </p>
    <input class="input" type="text" required>
    <input class="add-btn" type="button" value="Add">
  </div>
```

A few explanatory remarks: I use a delegated event handling which simplifies matters considerably: instead of having to attach events each time you create new items you do it once for the parent container. In my script I treat each checkbox of class "checkbox",  found within `.list` as a "signal for removal".